How to translate the term "baby" as in "burn, baby, burn?"
I have a translation project which includes the phrase "burn, baby, burn, disco inferno." This is a reference to the song Disco Inferno by The Trammps and is used in the game's narration to refer to something which is actually burning. I am not sure the usual translations for "baby" in the dictionary (e.g. Schatz) apply here, since as far as I can tell it is not used as a term of endearment for a woman, but as a sort of intensifying particle, meaning something similar to "hell yeah." Please advise.

Baby is a perfectly valid German word (and used both for infants and adults). Not sure it must be translated at all (but it must be capitalized). Additionally, the reference may stay more visible that way.

No one will get the reference if you translate it.

Germans frequently use short English phrases as is, I would strongly suspect this is the right approach here.

I agree with @infinitezero: Leave the phrase as it is or change the reference completely (see Merlin Nester's answer). What you do depends on your target audience. If it's younger people who are familiar with English and/or internet culture, do the former (as you're talking about a game I suspect this is the case). If it's older people, do the latter.

"Schatz" would indeed be wrong, because "Schatz" is an expression of endearment, although not necessarily in its figurative meaning for a woman (or, more general, for a beloved one, women could address their spouses in this way too), but in a more literal way. An avid philatelist might call the cornerstone of his collection "mein Schatz" too.
Instead the diminutive "Schätzchen" could work. One can address all sorts of things by it as it is (mainly but) not necessarily used for persons. One could address, say, a car by:

Dieses Schätzchen ist schnell.

Here "Schätzchen" would rather be translated as "thing", like in This thing is fast. The word also contains some element of endearment, but that could easily be ironically turned. E.g. an arsonist muttering

Brenne, [mein] Schätzchen, brenne!

to the building he just set on fire would work. It would express the wish for that building to truly continue to burn rather than any affection for the building.

In "Brenn', mein Schatz, brenn'" the terminology "Schatz" is ironic; it means the thing that burns is of value to someone (else) and the arsonist is thrilled by the fact of destroying property.

Somehow any such 'psychopathic' usage of "Schatz" feels like a reference to gollum for me

Maybe you can get away without a translation? Many Germans speak English and the language has been heavily influenced by english terms.
If it is a song which a German would happen to know it would not be uncommon to ironically say "burn, baby burn" when regarding a burning object. Especially lyrics would come across as awkward if translated.
Maybe you can replace the song altogether and use a German song about fire?

Rammstein -> "Feuer Frei" from "Feuer Frei"
Rammstein -> "Willst du dich von etwas trennen, musst du es verbrennen" from "Benzin"
Marteria, Yasha, Miss Platnum -> "Feuer!" from "Feuer"
Johannes Oerding -> "Alles brennt, alles geht in Flammen auf. Alles was bleibt, sind Asche und Rauch." from "Alles brennt"
Rosenstolz -> "Ich geh in Flammen auf" from "Ich geh in Flammen auf"
ASP -> "Ich will brennen" from "Ich will brennen"
KUMMER -> "Dein Leben liegt in Scherben und das Haus steht in Flammen aber alles wird gut" from "Der letzte Song"


And Disco Inferno definitely is a song that most Germans can be expected to know.

I'd argue that Disco Inferno might even be more widely known than Feuer frei or Benzin or any other sond suggested here. While I like the idea of using a german song reference, just keeping the original reference might just be best.

Yessss. When all else fails... use a German song about fire!

If you do that it is important to leave at least the surrounding burn in original English as well. 'Brenne, baby, brenne' would fail on several levels.

A note: even if one does not know "disco inferno", the phrase "burn baby burn" is known in german - those who don't know the song (like me) may still know it from movies or literature referencing (I assume) the song. I, personally, would not at all be surprised to find some character quoting it (in the original english) when reading a book in german.

is Feuer Frei really a good example, seeing as it's not a reference to burning, but rather the command to fire at will (and the other lyrics aren't especially concerned with fire either, so it's not even really used as wordplay as Rammstein are wont to do)

@Syndic Your comment piqued my interest, and I looked it up: the phrase “burn, baby, burn” originated as the slogan of a ’60s DJ, Magnificent Montague, well before “Disco Inferno.” It was then used as a catchphrase during the Watts riots in Los Angeles. Wikipedia has an article on the phrase, even. I doubt many people actually know that history, though.

@Tristan I beg to differ. Feuer Frei is about burning and fire, especially if you have seen them perform the song life at a concert. Also Feuer Frei! is somewhat a wordplay in this case meaning fire at will but literally with fire:
"Getadelt wird, wer Schmerzen kennt
Vom Feuer, das die Haut verbrennt
Ich werf ein Licht in mein Gesicht
Ein heißer Schrei, Feuer frei!"

@airace3 ah good point

All those song examples are quite serious, I would rather suggest something like "Hurra, hurra die Schule brennt" which paints the fire in a more positive light.

This is a tough one to translate.
In the original song, the "burn" metaphorically means "dance," and "baby" here is indeed something like "Schatz," a term of endearment...presumably for a woman, but it's not really clear. It's meant as a hype song to get people excited about dancing in a disco club.
The problem is that the phrase "burn, baby, burn" has taken on a much broader cultural resonance beyond the song where it originated. Usually it means something like "hell yeah, go for it," especially in a situation that calls for a bit of gumption, daring, or boldness.
The "___, baby, ___" formula has occasionally been used as a verbal meme. For example, the phrase "drill, baby, drill," popularized by Republican Vice Presidential candidate Sarah Palin in 2008 when she was advocating for an expansion of US petroleum production is well-known in US political circles.
I also occasionally see the phrase used in a literal way, in which case it takes on a sinister tone. Someone saying "burn, baby, burn" about something actually burning will come off to a native US English speaker as a little unhinged. Perhaps I'm reading into a little too deeply, but I think that its literal use crosses an unspoken boundary from boldness into recklessness. It's because the original song is so joyful and such a classic "good times" song that to use it in the context of someone literally burning something (unless perhaps it's a celebratory burning, like a bonfire?) comes across as a bit sadistic, like they're getting pleasure from the burning. For that reason, comparing the song to something like "Feuer Frei" by Rammstein is inappropriate--"fire" isn't used in the same way at all.
Therefore, to come to your question about how to translate "baby," I would say it depends:

Definitely do not translate it as the German "Baby" unless the original song and that phrase are very well-known among German speakers. Nothing about the phrase "burn, baby, burn" refers to an actual human baby.
If the literal burning is something positive and happy, or if it's a metaphorical burning (which you've indicated it isn't), then I would use "hell yeah!" or some other intensifying particle.
If the literal burning is something negative and especially if there's something sinister about it, I would use some word or phrase to suggest that the person commenting on the burning is a bit unhinged or sadistic, perhaps even evil.

EDIT: I don't have enough reputation to add or respond to comments, but one of the comments to another answer suggests that in the song "Brenn', mein Schatz, brenn," "Schatz" is used ironically to indicate that the arsonist is taking joy in burning something that's valued by someone else. I don't know that song, but that's exactly the correct sentiment conveyed by someone saying "burn, baby, burn" about something literally burning.

I'd argue that the German Baby is a perfectly finde translation in this case. Just like in English, it is commonly used as a term of endearment (like "Schatz") or in bad pickup-lines ("Ey Baby, kann ich deine Nummer haben?"). There are many German language songs where "Baby" does not refer to a human baby as well, e.g. DJ Ötzis Hey Baby.

@xyldke DJ Ötzis "Hey Baby" is perhaps not the best example of the use of the German word, it arguably uses the English one.

@Hulk That's true, I picked the wrong example. There are many other songs that use the word in German as well (Einmal um die Welt by Cro, Manchmal kommt die Liebe einfach so by Helene Fischer, even Baby, du bist nicht alleine by Michael Horn, which came out in 1973)

The phrase "burn, baby, burn" was in wide use long before The Trampps. AFAIK it became widespread during the 1965 Watts Riots in Los Angeles.

Rumors spread that the police had kicked a pregnant woman who was present at the scene. Six days of civil unrest followed, motivated in part by allegations of police abuse. Nearly 14,000 members of the California Army National Guard helped suppress the disturbance, which resulted in 34 deaths,as well as over $40 million in property damage. It was the city's worst unrest until the Rodney King riots of 1992.

WATTS: THE LEGACY : ‘Burn, Baby, Burn!’ : What Began as a Radio Disc Jockey’s Soulful Cry of Delight Became a National Symbol of Urban Rebellion

So prominent was the slogan that it became the password to safety in riot areas. A black newsman saw groups of rioters not only shouting “Burn, baby burn” at fires but using it to greet each other, “I, too, learned to shout ‘Burn, baby, burn’ after several shots were fired at me,”’ he wrote on the fourth night of the riot.

I've no idea how you can translate it. Can you leave it untranslated, perhaps with a footnote?
Just a thought: look for a German translation of Terminator 2: Judgment Day. How does it handle the phrase: Hasta la vista, baby?

The German synchronisation of Terminator 2 uses "Hasta la vista, Baby" as well. But the phrase is explained in the movie, so it's understood to be a colloquial phrase with a set meaning and not a regular German sentence.
